# Fastest way possible to validate a string to be only Alphas, or a given string set

Tags: c#, string, contains, alpha

I need the absoulute fastest way possible to validate an input string against a given rule. In this case lest say Alpha only characters.

I can think of a number of ways both verbose and non verbose. However speed in execution is of the essence. So If anybody can offer their pearls of wisdom I would be massivly grateful.

I'm avoiding regex to get away from the overhead of creating the expression object. However  am open to revisit this if people think this is the FASTEST option.

Current Ideas include:
1)

```
    internal static bool Rule_AlphaOnly(string Value)
    {
        char[] charList = Value.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < charList.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!((charList[i] >= 65 && charList[i] <= 90) || (charList[i] >= 97 && charList[i] <= 122)))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

2)

```
    char[] charList = Value.ToCharArray();
    return charList.All(t => ((t >= 65 && t <= 90) || (t >= 97 && t <= 122)));
```

Thought about also using the "Contains" methods.

Any ideas welcomed.
Many thanks

3)
    for (int i = 0; i < Value.Length; i++)
    {
    if(!char.IsLetter(Value, i))
    {
     return false;
    }
    }

Comment: The best way is to just try a bunch of different solutions, and profile them. Do it for ~1000 strings and measure the elapsed seconds for each method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure on the speed of this one but what about...

```
foreach(char c in Value)
{
   if(!char.IsLetter(c))
      return false;
}
```

Comment: Well this uses the for each which I believe is still slower than the for i char[i] looper, however will look at the char.IsLetter bit. Thanks

Comment: @DubMan Don’t believe, measure. There is no technical reason why this should be slower than a `for` loop with an index.

Comment: I generally always find a for quicker than a for each.  The above here can be expressed as a lovely one liner: return _value.All(char.IsLetter);   But this is of course using Linq, and that is notorious at being slow. So I'm going to test these examples on a load.  Thank you all for input though.

Comment: Here a benchmark with RegEx, IsLetter method and ASCII compare > [Verify is letter or digit (Benchmark in c#)](https://github.com/fernandezja/verify-is-letter-or-digit-benchmark)

Answer (score 4):

Both codes can be made more efficient by removing the `ToCharArray` call and thus avoiding a copy: you can access the individual characters of a string directly.

Of those two ways I would strongly opt for the second unless you can show that it’s too slow. Only then would I switch to the first, but replace the `for` loop with a `foreach` loop.

Oh, and neither of your codes treats Unicode correctly. If you had used a regular expression with a proper character class, then this wouldn’t be an issue. **Correctness first, performance second.**

Comment: actually, .NET's regex don't handle Unicode correctly. They don't work properly on anything outside the BMP (it's all just surrogates). An example: `Regex.IsMatch("", @"\p{Lu}")`

Comment: @Porges Good catch. But if even regular expressions don’t handle this correctly, handling this by hand is probably even harder – case in point, `char.IsLetter` also handles this incorrectly.

Comment: Yep, handling Unicode in .NET sucks. To iterate over Unicode strings you need to either use the `char.IsSurrogate` methods manually, or `StringInfo` (which additionally will handle combining characters). You can then use `char.IsLetter(string,index)` on the character which will handle it correctly.

Comment: Ok then... I've gone with the following, any objections or further comments? for (int i = 0; i < Value.Length; i++)
     {
       if(!char.IsLetter(Value, i))
       {
         return false;
       }
     }

Comment: @DubMan Hm. Unlike @Porges I found that `char.IsLetter(value, i)` works no better than the other variant, at least on the example he posted. Perhaps it makes a difference for combining diacritic marks, I haven’t tested that.

Answer (score 0):

After C# compiler and JIT are done optimizing it, I doubt this will be much slower than manual `for` loop:

```
return Value.All(char.IsLetter);
```

---

If you need to check for arbitrary set of characters, do something like this:

```
var set = new HashSet<char>(new[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' /* Etc... */ });
return Value.All(set.Contains);
```

Unless the `set` is trivial and can be "emulated" efficiently via few `if`s, the hashtable lookup is bound to be as fast a solution as it gets.